# Protégé import from http://w3id.org/XXX

Tags: owl, semantic-web, ontology, protege, virtuoso

I am having problems importing two ontologies in Protégé. These ontologies are stored in the following links [Onto1](http://193.144.237.227:8890/DAV/home/dba/Ontologies/measurements4EEPSA.owl) and [Onto2](http://193.144.237.227:8890/DAV/home/dba/Ontologies/bim4EEPSA.owl) and are also in the W3ID.ORG URL re-direction service ([Onto1Redirection](https://w3id.org/measurements4eepsa) and [Onto2Redirection](https://w3id.org/bim4eepsa)).

I tried to import both of them using Protege's **Direct Import => Add => Import an ontology contained in a document located on the web** option. I tried introducing both the original OWL file's and the redirection URL.

However, after saving the ontology and loading it, imports are not correctly done (i.e. one or the other is not imported).

Any guidance in this matter will be appreciated.

Comment: What Protégé version are you using? Have you tried downloading the ontologies and using **Direct Import => Add => Import an ontology contained in a specific file**? Both import options seem to work for me in Protégé 5.2.0 on a Mac.

Comment: It is a Protégé 4.3.0. I am trying to make the ontology public, so it has to make the imports from a public URL.

Comment: Any chance you can update to 5.x and test it there? It works for me with that version (also with URL import).

Comment: I have updated it to 5.1.0, and I think it works. Both ontologies should be imported by the ontology in [link](https://w3id.org/eepsa). Does it work in your version too?

Comment: Why did you "update" to 5.1.0 if there is already the newer 5.2.0? That's a bit a strange isn't it?